# Trying to customize login page for mobile, interfering with desktop version of login page

Tags: theming, users

I've been trying to customize the login/retrieve password/create account pages on the mobile version of my website for a couple of weeks now with little success. I haven't found a satisfactory answer to my problem anywhere. The closest I've come is Dropal's solution [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1949472#comment-7892233). This actually seemed to work (after I also created a page--user.tpl.php page in addition to the recommended page--user--login.tpl.php). It seemed to work, that is, until it didn't.

Again, I'm trying to stylize *only the mobile version of my site*, which I created in a sub-domain. When I put these customized login/password pages into the sub-domain and clear the cache, the mobile version looks great...but it totally destroys the login/retrieve password/create account pages on the desktop version of my site, causing it to look ridiculously wrong.

This makes no sense to me at all. I haven't created custom page--user.tpl.php or page--user--login.tpl.php files in the directory for my desktop version. So why are the sub-domain files interfering with with the regular domain files? So, so, so confused. Can someone please shed some light on why this is happening?

Comment: Please provide some information on how you are achieving separation between site versions.

Comment: Thanks, @Darvanen. If I understand your question correctly, I added redirect code to the subdomain in my main site's htaccess file. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Ok... so that sounds like you have two completely separate sites?  Do they share content?  If so, how?

Comment: They do share content, yes. Basically, the subdomain is a mirror of my main site in (almost) every way except that I've modified the subdomain's css so that the subdomain site is optimized for viewing on mobile devices. Also, like I said in my first post, the two sites are different in that the subdomain also has the customized page--user.tpl.php and page--user--login.tpl.php  files whereas my main site doesn't have these customized login page files.